# Chrome DIV not fully painted

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

I am using Chrome version 41.0.2272.118.

There is a specific DIV on the page where if I change its contents by assigning its innerHTML or innerText then another DIV on the page is corrupted.

The result of the corruption is that the corrupted DIV's right padding is no longer drawn. However the DIV takes up the same space and it has the same width according to the developer tools. Additionally the corrupted DIV's bottom border is still drawn even though there is no div above it.
Oddly even though the div has the same width any text in the div is rewrapped and sentences in it take up more lines.

Changing the innerHTML or innerText of other DIVs on the page does not result in any corruption.

Sometime a later DOM modification can trigger fixing the corrupted DIV so that its right padding is again drawn and it is rewrapped the way it was before it was corrupted.

---

Here is a small example of the problem:

1. If an absolute div is within a table
2. If the content of the absolute div is changed using innerHTML in an asynchronous callback
3. And this was done before the asynchronous callback `document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
4. Then all cells in the first column of the table will be painted with the wrong width for the background

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="twoandthree">
                    <div id="two">two</div>
                    <div id="three">three</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">update two</button>
```

CSS:

```
#twoandthree {
    position:relative;
    min-width:80px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#two {
    position: absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
#three {
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
    background: lightblue;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.style.cursor = "";
        two.innerHTML = "aaa";
    }, 500);
});
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the two DIVs?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I notice weird rendering quirks with Chrome as well. Try applying `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` to your CSS force GPU acceleration.

Here is some more info about it: http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It did not help to put that on the corrupted div or one of its children.